# Pi not booting: Error on SD and only flashing cursor when booting

Tags: pi-2

One day I started my Raspberry Pi and it crashed, so I flicked the power off.
I restarted it and it booted like normal but I noticed an error avahi (SD issue).
When it came to the desktop part it stayed black with white cursor flashing top left corner.

Is it worth buying a new Raspberry Pi or is there a fix?

Pi Specs:

Raspberry Pi 2
Made by Fuze.

Comment: Why is it that your title has the words `Error on SD`, yet you make no mention of replacing the SD?

Comment: Have you tried a new SD card and base image or different power supply?

Comment: It's nothing to do with the SD card; her parenthetical comment (likely) refers to `DNS-SD`, one of the protocols used by avahi.

Comment: @ScratchCoder : Can you get an SSH connection to your RPi?; i.e. from a terminal on your PC/Mac, can you connect via `ssh pi@<ip addr>` ?

Comment: Jsotola, if you actually read my question you would know. Dbmitch, that is what I asked at the bottom kind off (is it worth it)? Seamus, I can't get a connection as it is not connected to the internet until it boots as of a WiFi adaptor,  that I have to enter password once desktop is reached.

Comment: Bought a new raspberry pi since no one could be bothered to reply. Thanks for the people who actually TRIED to help instead of criticising what I put. :)